# How can I implement a min-heap of f64 with Rust's BinaryHeap?

Tags: rust, min-heap

I want to populate a binary heap with floats--more specifically, I'd like to implement a min-heap.

It seems that floats do not support `Ord` and thus aren't usable out of the box. My attempts to wrap them have so far failed. However it seems that if I could wrap them then I could also implement `Ord` in such a way that it would effectively make `BinaryHeap` a min-heap.

Here's an example of a wrapper I tried:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct MinNonNan(f64);

impl Eq for MinNonNan {}

impl Ord for MinNonNan {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &MinNonNan) -> Ordering {
        let ord = self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap();
        match ord {
            Ordering::Greater => Ordering::Less,
            Ordering::Less => Ordering::Greater,
            Ordering::Equal => ord
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is `pop` returns the values as though it were a max-heap.

What exactly do I need to do to populate a `BinaryHeap` with `f64` values as a min-heap?

Comment: Please show how do you insert and pop from the BinaryHeap<MinNonNan>.

Comment: @kennytm `minheap.push(MinNonNan(42.0))` and `if let Some(MinNonNan(root)) = minheap.pop() ...`

Comment: On a hunch, I'd try implementing `PartialOrd` to agree with `Ord`. They aren't really meant to contradict each other -- the compiler may make optimizations based on the assumption that they are effectively the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Crate-based solution

Instead of writing your own `MinNonNan`, consider using the [ordered-float](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/1.0.1/ordered_float/struct.NotNan.html) crate + the [`std::cmp::Reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) type.

```rust
type MinNonNan = Reverse<NotNan<f64>>;
```

## Manual solution

Since you are `#[derive]`ing `PartialOrd`, the `.gt()`, `.lt()` etc methods still compare normally, i.e. `MinNonNan(42.0) < MinNonNan(47.0)` is still true. The `Ord` bound only restricts you to provide strictly-ordered types, it doesn't mean the implementation will use `.cmp()` instead of `<`/`>`/`<=`/`>=` everywhere, nor the compiler will suddenly change those operators to use the `Ord` implementation.

If you want to flip the order, you need to implement `PartialOrd` as well.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct MinNonNan(f64);

impl PartialOrd for MinNonNan {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        other.0.partial_cmp(&self.0)
    }
}

impl Ord for MinNonNan {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &MinNonNan) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is for a small script and I do not want to use external libs if it can be avoided. However thank you for pointing out those crates!

Comment: @maxcountryman Rust is done to easily use extern crates, just like in javascript for example.

Answer (score 9):

## Working Examples

### Crate-based solution

```rust
use ordered_float::NotNan; // 2.7.0
use std::{cmp::Reverse, collections::BinaryHeap};

fn main() {
    let mut minheap = BinaryHeap::new();
    minheap.push(Reverse(NotNan::new(2.0).unwrap()));
    minheap.push(Reverse(NotNan::new(1.0).unwrap()));
    minheap.push(Reverse(NotNan::new(42.0).unwrap()));
    if let Some(Reverse(nn)) = minheap.pop() {
        println!("{}", nn.into_inner());
    }
}
```

### Manual solution

```rust
use std::{cmp::Ordering, collections::BinaryHeap};

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct MinNonNan(f64);

impl Eq for MinNonNan {}

impl PartialOrd for MinNonNan {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        other.0.partial_cmp(&self.0)
    }
}

impl Ord for MinNonNan {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &MinNonNan) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut minheap = BinaryHeap::new();
    minheap.push(MinNonNan(2.0));
    minheap.push(MinNonNan(1.0));
    minheap.push(MinNonNan(42.0));
    if let Some(MinNonNan(root)) = minheap.pop() {
        println!("{:?}", root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does this solution ignore decimal part during comparison?

Comment: @Klesun [just you](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4cd979ce0abca6b970fe1608d9cce88a)