# How to create a minimum BinaryHeap?

Tags: rust, binary-heap

I'm trying to solve [leetcode problem 703, largest_element_in_a_stream](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-a-stream/) in Rust.

I want to use the `BinaryHeap` to solve this problem, but the `BinaryHeap` in Rust is the maximum heap by default. I don't know how to transform it to a maximum heap.

I found answers in similar questions:

- [How do I create a BinaryHeap that pops the smallest value, not the largest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489368/how-do-i-create-a-binaryheap-that-pops-the-smallest-value-not-the-largest)
- [How can I implement a min-heap of f64 with Rust's BinaryHeap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949939/how-can-i-implement-a-min-heap-of-f64-with-rusts-binaryheap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But the answer in the two questions uses some special struct and overloads the `Ord` trait, I want to solve it for primitives such as `i32`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: The duplicates you've identified *are* how you solve it: `BinaryHeap<std::cmp::Reverse<i32>>`. In fact, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489427/155423) already shows how to create a heap with `i32` values.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer,I was know little about how to use the `Reverse` before that.The offical example in API is a bit simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want a min-heap, you could just negate each value you put it in the heap & negate each you take out.

Note: As @Shepmaster alludes to, there is a single i32 negative value which does not have a corresponding positive one (to balance 0, which is its own negative).  If you need to handle this value, this technique will not work, at least not without a bit of finessing.

Comment: Negating is not a good solution as the largest negative and positive `i32` values have different magnitudes and you cannot flip them. `assert_eq!(std::i32::MIN, -std::i32::MAX)` fails and `assert_eq!(-std::i32::MIN, std::i32::MAX)` panics.

Comment: @Shep: Not correct; you *can* represent the negative of the maximum positive value, it just isn't the most negative value (which isn't important).  It *is* true that you cannot represent the negative of the most negative value.

Comment: I didn't state that you can't represent the negative of the maximum positive value though, just that you can't flip the two extremes due to the different magnitudes. I then provided code that shows that the magnitudes are different.

Comment: "You cannot flip them": I guess I interpreted this as "you cannot represent the negation each", which is not true, and my only concern is with representation.  I make the distinction because the *only* input value that breaks this approach is the most negative.